# Adding and accessing resource files to Play Framework application

Tags: java, playframework, cloud-foundry

I am running a PlayFramework 2 application. The application builds a client authenticated SSL session to a 2nd server. To accomplish this I am storing a Java Keystore file in a resource directory. Everything runs fine on my local box.  Next I create a dist package for upload to Cloud Foundry which essentially builds a war file with a buch of Jars.  Any idea how I can access the Keystore from my java code once its compiled into a Jar and uploaded to CloudFoundry?  Any direction would be greatly appreciated.  Here is current code snippet.

Best,

SR

```
//READS THE JAVA KEYSTORE FILE FROM A RELATIVE LOCATION
File clientKS = new File("resource/devportal.jks");

//SET CONNECTION PARAMS             
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setSSLSocketFactory(getFactory(clientKS, passphrase.toCharArray()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is no other way than to use a java.io.File, you may want to try getting ahold of it by putting it in the classpath of your app and do something like

```
AnyClassOfYourApp.class.getResource("devportal.jks").getFile()
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I will try it and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while but try this:

```
    //TESTING BY USING INCLUDED KEYSTORE IN JAR FILE
    String ksPath = "/res/devportal.jks";
    URL jksURL = PostNvp.class.getResource(ksPath);
    File jksStore = new File(jksURL.toURI());
    //TESTING
```

Where PostNvp is my java class PostNvp.java where this code snippet lives.